# How to ensure unique value in mapping (like unique nickname for address)?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, storage

I am creating smart contract where I want each account to have **unique** nick/name attached to address. Here is example code:

```
mapping (address => string) members;
function isMember() constant returns bool() {
    return members[msg.sender] != "";
}

function register(string _name) {
    if (members[msg.sender] != "") {
        throw("Already registered");
    }

    /* now check if name is already taken...
    foreach (name : members) {
        if (name == _name) {
            throw();
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Is it possible to utilize `mapping` to ensure that each nick/name entered into members is unique? Or my best course of action would be to create another property that just holds list of nicks already in use? What is better approach from gas usage standpoint (considering iterating huge lists should incur higher costs)?

Answer (score 5):

I changed your `string` to `bytes32` to avoid an additional challenge of doing this with strings - for more clarity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Checker {

    mapping (address => bytes32) members; // using bytes32 instead of string
    mapping (bytes32 => bool) isTaken;

    function isMember(address member) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return (members[member] != 0);
    }

    function isSet(bytes32 name) public view returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return (isTaken[name]);
    }

    function register(bytes32 _name) public returns(bool success){
        require(members[msg.sender] == "");
        require(!isSet(_name));
        members[msg.sender] = _name;
        isTaken[_name] = true;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: shouldn't it be "isNotSet" instead of "isSet" for the check?

Comment: I don't think so. The default `isTaken` is `false`, so _not taken_. So, if `isTaken[index] == false` then `isSet == false`. It's quick little scribble so if there's a mistake, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: but wont require(isSet[_name]) fail if isSet returns false?

Comment: Good catch. Now I see it. It should be `require(!isSet(...`, not set. I fixed it in the example.